# Time sheet module - Gettimesheetdata subroutine

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have come a long way on this first Access project of mine but presently terribly stuck at this point for over two weeks!

This part is the timesheet module where there is a timesheetform and a timesheetsubform; on the header part of the form there is a combobox where the user picks the week ending (Friday) date. This week ending date is the main criteria for the whole timesheet. Everything till this point seems to be working fine thanks to one of Ms. Fennema’s codes which I was able to adapt.

Once the date is picked on the combobox, I must put a code in its afterupdate event (Gettimesheetdata subroutine), to first check the main table (tblTimeSheetData) if there are any workhours for the 5 weekdays of that week; (maybe through a query on the fly) and if there are, it should put them in the proper fields in the subform through the temp table so that the user can verify that that specific week's timesheet is already complete or make adjustments to it. If there are no records it would mean that this is a new timesheet! In the case that it’s a new timesheet, selecting the projects and entering the hours for the weekdays and save them to main table also seems to work (Writetimesheetdata subroutine below). As you enter the hours per day based on the project, it populates the temp table and a ‘Save the Worksheet’ command button converts the horizontal data to vertical on the main table. I would really appreciate any help to guide me in the right direction on the Gettimesheetdata subroutine.

Thank you.

Here is the code for the Writetimesheetdata subroutine:

```
Public Sub WriteTimesheetData()

     Set rstTime = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTimeSheetData", _
     dbOpenDynaset)
     Set rstTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTimeSheetDataTemp")

With rstTemp
  .MoveLast
  .MoveFirst
  lngCount = .RecordCount
  Debug.Print lngCount & " records to write"

  If lngCount > 0 Then
     'Attempt to find matching record in tblTimeSheetData
     'Create or edit one record in tblTimeSheetData for each weekday
     'that has hours worked
     Do While Not .EOF
        lngProjectsID = Nz(![ProjectsID])
        lngActivityCode = Nz(![ActivityCode])

        dblWorkHours = Nz(![MondayWorkHours])

        If dblWorkHours > 0 Then
           dteWork = DateAdd("d", -4, _
              GetProperty("TimesheetWeekEnding", ""))


           If lngActivityCode <> 0 Then
              strSearch = "[ProjectsID] = " & lngProjectsID _
                 & " And [WorkDate] = " & Chr(35) & dteWork _
                 & Chr(35) & " And [ActivityCode] = " _
                 & lngActivityCode
           End If

           Debug.Print "Search string: " & strSearch
           rstTime.FindFirst strSearch

           If rstTime.NoMatch = False Then
              'Edit existing record
              rstTime.Edit
              rstTime![WorkHours] = dblWorkHours
              rstTime.Update

           Else
              'Add new record
              rstTime.AddNew
              rstTime![ProjectsID] = ![ProjectsID]
              rstTime![WorkDate] = dteWork
              rstTime![ActivityCode] = ![ActivityCode]
              rstTime![WorkHours] = dblWorkHours
              rstTime.Update
           End If

           'repeat same code for Tue, Wed, Thu and Fri

        End If

        .MoveNext
     Loop
  End If
 End With

ErrorHandlerExit:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number _
  & " in WriteTimesheetData procedure; " _
  & "Description: " & Err.Description
Resume ErrorHandlerExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much of this will be useful to you but perhaps it will give you some ideas. I did some testing in my db to track Little League umpire assignments. First, created a temp table with the necessary fields.

A saved CROSSTAB query object with static filter criteria can be the source for an INSERT action but dynamic parameters in CROSSTAB query object cause error; however, VBA can deal with that.

```
Dim rsPos As DAO.Recordset, rsSource As DAO.Recordset, rsTemp As DAO.Recordset
Set rsPos = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Position FROM Rates;")
Set rsTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM temp1 WHERE 1=1;")
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM temp1"
While Not rsPos.EOF
    Set rsSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TRANSFORM First(Rates.Rate) AS FirstRate " & _
                    "SELECT Rates.Position FROM Rates " & _
                    "WHERE (((Rates.Position)='" & rsPos!Position & "')) " & _
                    "GROUP BY Rates.Position PIVOT Rates.RateLevel;")
    While Not rsSource.EOF
        rsTemp.AddNew
        rsTemp!Position = rsSource!Position
        rsTemp!Junior = rsSource!Junior
        rsTemp!Major = rsSource!Major
        rsTemp!Minor = rsSource!Minor
        rsTemp!MinorA = rsSource!MinorA
        rsSource.MoveNext
        rsTemp.Update
    Wend
    rsSource.Close
    rsPos.MoveNext
Wend
rsPos.Close
```

Following code accomplishes the same output without CROSSTAB:

```
Dim rsPos As DAO.Recordset, rsSource As DAO.Recordset, rsTemp As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
Set rsPos = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Position FROM Rates;")
Set rsTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Position, Junior, Major, Minor, MinorA FROM temp1 WHERE 1=1;")
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete FROM temp1"
While Not rsPos.EOF
    Set rsSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Position, RateLevel, Rate FROM Rates WHERE Position = '" & rsPos!Position & "' ORDER BY RateLevel;")
    While Not rsSource.EOF
        rsTemp.AddNew
        rsTemp!Position = rsSource!Position
        For i = 1 To 4
            rsTemp.Fields(i) = rsSource!Rate
            rsSource.MoveNext
        Next
        rsTemp.Update
    Wend
    rsSource.Close
    rsPos.MoveNext
Wend
rsPos.Close
```

Comment: Thank you June7. It surely got me thinking. It's just too big a task to get help on. I am trying to apply a modular approach and am almost there; just need some advice on doing a query on a query in vba but I'll start another thread for that. Thanks so much!